# Binding Converter how to pass a parameter to function

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, converters

In my window.xaml I have the following code:

```
 xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:HMIPlc.Helpers"

 <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorOnChange"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=varUnit.InSimulation, Converter={StaticResource ColorOnChange}}"/>
```

I want to give also a value in a string "Yellow" or "Orange" to the function, so I can use the same function for different rectangles with different colors.

My ColorConverter.cs class inside the Helpers directory:

```
public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public ColorConverter()
    {
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool tempBool = (bool)value;
        if(tempBool == true)
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
        } else
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So that I can determine in my XAML if the color has to be orange or yellow. Is there any good method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `CommandParameter` property to a `Brush` or `Color` and cast the "parameter" argument in your converter:

```
public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Color color = (Color)parameter;
        bool tempBool = (bool)value;
        if (tempBool == true)
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(color);
        }
        else
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(color);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML**:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=varUnit.InSimulation, Converter={StaticResource ColorOnChange},
        ConverterParameter={x:Static Colors.Orange}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to provide additional values to a converter, you can either:

a) Add additional properties on the converter which can then be assigned in XAML:

```cs
public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Color BackupColor { get; set; }

    public ColorConverter()
    {

    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool tempBool = (bool)value;
        if(tempBool == true)
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
        } else
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```xml
...
<converters:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorOnChange" BackupColor="Yellow"/>
...
```

b) Leverage [the ConverterParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.converterparameter?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) which is usually a string literal:

```xml
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=varUnit.InSimulation, Converter={StaticResource ColorOnChange}, CommandParameter='Yellow'}"/>
```

Comment: It is not `CommandParameter`, but [`ConverterParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.converterparameter?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) for bindings.

Comment: And it's not "usually a string literal" but any `object`.

Comment: @mm8 yes, any object, but in most cases this will end up being a string or number unless you like creating objects in XAML because you can't use bindings in converter parameters :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind multiple values, use a [`MultiValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). I use the more general type [`Brush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.brush?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) here, so you are not limited to binding a [`SolidColorBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

```
public class ColorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (values.Length != 3 ||
          !(values[0] is bool value) ||
          !(values[1] is Brush brushTrue) ||
          !(values[2] is Brush brushFalse))
         return Binding.DoNothing;

      return value ? brushTrue : brushFalse;
   }

   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

Then use a [`MultiBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.multibinding?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and specify the property to be bound, as well as the brushes. In order to reference a built-in brush, you can use the static [`Brushes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.brushes?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) type with `x:Static`.

```
<Rectangle>
   <Rectangle.Fill>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ColorOnChange}">
         <Binding Path="varUnit.InSimulation"/>
         <Binding Source="{x:Static Brushes.Orange}"/>
         <Binding Source="{x:Static Brushes.White}"/>
      </MultiBinding>
   </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```